# Added summernote settings into project

Tags: django, summernote

I'm currently using django summernote in my project. It works well and these are my settings.

```
 'summernote': {
        # As an example, using Summernote Air-mode
        'airMode': False,

        'toolbar': [
            ['style', ['style']],
            ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'superscript', 'subscript',
                      'strikethrough', 'clear']],
            ['height', ['height']],

        ],

    },
```

I'd like to add some settings that pertains to the widget the opens when you select an image within summernote. The official summernote documentation specifies that you can update the settings with the following, but I'm not sure how to put this into a format that my settings.py file will like.

```
popover: {
  image: [
          ['image', ['resizeFull', 'resizeHalf', 'resizeQuarter', 'resizeNone']]
        ],

}
```

I tried adding this, but I get an error saying my secret key can't be empty. Looks like all my tags are closed.

```
'popover': [
    'image',: [
        [
            'image', ['resizeFull', 'resizeHalf', 'resizeQuarter', 'resizeNone']
        ]
    ],
    
],
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you set a `SECRET_KEY` in your Django settings?

Comment: Yes, I've got a secret_key. It's at the top of my settings file and these summernote settings are at the bottom. Not sure why django would complain about the secret key with the addition of my code.